# What is a proper way to pass object as a prop via vue router?

Tags: vue.js

I have a PreviewProduct component, which when clicked emits product object to App.vue file. Then I want to pass it to DetailedProduct component, like this:

```
handleProductClicked(product) {
      console.log(product),
      this.$router.push({ name: 'detailedProduct', params: { id: product.id, product: product}})
    }
```

These are my routes:

```
const routes = [
  { path: '/', component: HeroSection },
  { path: '/product/:id', name: 'detailedProduct', component: DetailedProduct, props: {
    product: Object
  }}
]
```

Firstly, it doesn't work. I get "Discarded invalid param(s) "product"". console.log(product) outputs the proper object though.
Am I on the right path, or is there a more proper way to passing props than via router?

I tried using query instead of params, but it passes a function instead of object

Comment: Both params and query only accept string or number type ,you can use JSON.stringify(product) to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

```
const routes = [
  { path: '/', component: HeroSection },
  { path: '/product/:id', name: 'detailedProduct', component: DetailedProduct, props:true
]
```

In Route props takes boolean. Make it true and pass the the object. Make sure your children component gets the props as a object . [More info](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props)